# Asynchronous NSURLConnection request responds multiple times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios5

I am facing weired issue. I am sending Asynchronus NSUrlrequest call but in return i am getting multiple time responde with some part of json

can someone please help me with what I did wrong.

code

```
NSString *_query = @"http://abc.com/index.php";

    NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[_requestString UTF8String] 
                                       length:[_requestString length]];


    __block NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_query]]; 

    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST" ];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData ];

    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

    [runLoop addTimer:timeOutTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

---

Response

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
    // check is response is a valid JSON?
    NSError *error;

    id jsonObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    BOOL isValid = [NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:jsonObj];


    NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data 
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Content: %@",content);

    if (isValid)
    {
        NSDictionary *data = [content JSONValue];
    }


    [content release];
}
```

Comment: I think you'll need to show us the code where you handle the response.

Comment: +1 on code.  We need to see the NSURLConnection delegate callbacks.

Comment: hi i want to upload image using post method in xml... you have any sample for this,..

Comment: @Rajneeshh071 - uploading image would be another question on S.O.  We shouldn't mixup different questions and answers in the same post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As data is received by the client, this callback gets called:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

didReceiveData is giving you data as it's receiving it and can be called multiple times with chunks of the data.

From the [NSURLConnection docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html):

> The delegate is periodically sent connection:didReceiveData: messages
>   as the data is received. The delegate implementation is responsible
>   for storing the newly received data.

From those docs:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the new data to receivedData.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}
```

When its all done, connectionDidFinishLoading will get called and your appended data is ready for you to use.

> Finally, if the connection succeeds in downloading the request, the
>   delegate receives the connectionDidFinishLoading: message. The
>   delegate will receive no further messages for the connection and the
>   NSURLConnection object can be released.

Comment: Thanks a ton bryanmac. So i was wrong, i wrote my code in **didReceiveData** delegate and the right way is it should be in **connectionDidFinishLoading**